# Essential Sacred Arts a Brahmin Must Know

Tags: rituals, brahmins, art, nature, crafts

I am wondering if there's any crafts or things a Brahmin (male) must know how to make for rituals and various other holy acts. If so please name them, how to make them, and possible substitutes for those residing outside of Bharata. I am sorry this is a weird question I just like making things, but most things are just artsy and useless I want something which can actually be used.

Comment: Sandhyavandana is the most essential rite yor a Brahmin to  cultivate & maintain brahmanya. Devibhagavata Purana clearly states that it isn't mandatory to worship Vishnu or Shiva, but it IS mandatory to perform Sandhyavandana. And even within Sandhyavandana, japa of the Gayatri is the most essential rite. See Devi Bhagavata Purana & Gayatri Tantra in this regard.

Comment: @অনু sure which verse?

Comment: @অনু how is this related to the question?